# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript

```
  function assign(id){

 return document.getElementById(id) ;
} 
var b = ['p','q','r','s','t','u','v'];
var a = ['fname','lname','email','password','r_password','g_m',"g_f"] ; 

 for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        var x = {} ;
     x[b[i]] = assign(a[i]) ;
      x[i].addEventListener('click', function() { alert(x[i].value) ;} ,false) ;

 }
```

I want just array of variables and IDs assign with them in for loop .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Amstell        i want to assign addEventListner with IDs in array a with variable array b .

Answer (score 3):

You're expecting `x[i]` to return the DOM element you just stored, but you're storing the DOM element at `x[b[i]]`, not `x[i]`. Be consistent, and that error will go away.

The code still won't work, though, because you're falling into the closure trap: When the click occurs, the event handler will use `i` *as it is then*, not as it was when the handler was created. So all the handlers will see `i` as `a.length` and fail.

I usually use a builder function to handle that:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var x = {};
    x[b[i]] = asign(a[i]);
    hookUp(i);
}
function hookUp(index) {
    x[b[index]].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(x[b[index]].value);
    }, false);
}
```

`hookUp` uses `index` (which we don't change) rather than `i`. (I also took a guess at which to use, `x[i]` or `x[b[i]]`.)

That said, if your goal is to alert the `value` of the element that was clicked, use `this` instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var x = {};
    x[b[i]] = asign(a[i]);
    x[b[i]].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(this.value);
    }, false);
}
```

or `Event#currentTarget`:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var x = {};
    x[b[i]] = asign(a[i]);
    x[b[i]].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        alert(e.currentTarget.value);
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: still error shown Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function asign(id){

     return document.getElementById(id) ;
    } 
    var a = ['a','b','c'];
    var b = ['fname','lname','email'] ; 

     for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
       (function(i){
         var x = {} ;
         x[b[i]] = asign(a[i]) ;
         x[b[i]].addEventListener('click', function() { alert(i+1) ;} ,false) ;
         })(i);

     }
```

```html
<div id="a">Div 1</div>
<div id="b">Div 2</div>
<div id="c">Div 3</div>
```